# Need to pass the search pattern dynamically to sed

Tags: regex, sed

I tried to pass the search pattern dynamically to sed in `s/SearchPattern/ReplacePattern/` action but its not taking the variable content like same action with direct parttern value.
Here is  the used code.

```
# assuming node='pcrf'
sed -e '/"$node"/s/^/#/' inittab > inittab.new && mv inittab.new inittab
```

The same search but using litterla pattern is working

```
sed -e '/pcrf/s/^/#/' inittab > inittab.new && mv inittab.new inittab.
```

So, please suggest me, how to use the content of the variable into the search.

Comment: This is because you have to use double quotes. Otherwise, the variable won't be expanded.

Comment: I have used double quotes only. please clarify where we have to use double quotes.

Comment: `sed -e '...'` is not double quotes. Also, you should give some sample input file and desired output, otherwise this is a bit blur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try:

```
sed -e "/$node/s/^/#/" inittab >. ...
```

#### add test

here is how it worked:

```
kent$  v=1

kent$  seq 15|sed "/$v/s/^/#/"  
#1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
#10
#11
#12
#13
#14
#15
```